# Нахождение записей с разными значениями поля

Tags: sql, oracle

Здравствуйте. Имеется запрос, выдающий например 2 строки. И одно из полей у этих двух строк одинаковое. Как мне сделать такое условие, что если значения этого поля в обоих строках одинаковые, тогда мне не должно выдать эти строчки вообще? То есть выдавать только такие строки, в которых различные значения именно в том поле которое мне нужно. Наверное как то нужно разбить по группам такие записи?

Comment: В подзапросе посчитать количество для каждого из значений, отобрать те, которые уникальны, использовать в критерии отбора.

Comment: @Akina количество чего?

Answer (score 0):

С помощью оконных функций, например:

```
select *
  from (select <columns>, 
               count() over (partition by "это поле") cnt
          from my_table)
 where cnt = 1
```

В столбце `cnt` считается количество повторов значений "этого поля", а во внешнем запросе выбираются только те значения, которые встречаются только один раз.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте подсчёт количества уникальных значений по данному полю.
Покажу на [примере sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af65ee/2):

```
select c.*,
    (select count(*) from city c1 where c1.descr = c.descr) as descr_count,
    (select count(*) from city c1 where c1.name = c.name) as name_count
from city c
having descr_count = 1 /* или name_count = 1 */
```

Например, город Moscow встречается 2 раза, поэтому его не надо выводить, тогда достаточно условия `name_count = 1`.
2-й случай - Рязань и Коломна с одинаковым описанием. В данном случае легко избавиться от них с помощью `descr_count = 1`.